# How do you save multiple records in SailsJS in one action?

Tags: node.js, nested, sails.js, waterline

I am wondering what the best practice would be for saving multiple records in an action that makes changes, particularly add and remove, to multiple records.  The end goal is to have one function have access to all of the changed data in the action.  Currently I am nesting the saves in order for the innermost saves to have access to the data in all the updated records.  Here is an example of how I am saving:

```
record1.save(function (error, firstRecord) {
  record2.save(function (erro, secondRecord) {
   record3.save(function (err, thirdRecord) {
    res.send({recordOne: firstRecord, recordTwo: secondRecord, recordThree: thirdRecord});
    });
  });
});
```

With this structure of saving, recordOne, recordTwo, and recordThree display the expected values on the server.  However, checking localhost/1337/modelName reveals that the models did not properly update and have incorrect data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built in promise engine [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise) to to that.

```js
   Promise.then(function() {
       return [record1.save(),record2.save(),record3.save()];
   }).spread(function(record1_saved,record2_saved,record3_saved){
       res.send({recordOne: record1_saved, recordTwo: record2_saved, recordThree: record3_saved});
       req.namespamce = this;
   }).catch(function(err){
           res.badRequest({
                error: err.message
            });
            req.namespamce = this;
   });
```